# Поменять местами элементы двумерного массива относительно побочной диагонали Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа исправно меняет элементы относительно главной диагонали. Примерно, что она выведет:

```
1 2 3        1 0 7
0 9 4 вывод: 2 9 6
7 6 5        3 4 5
```

Когда пользователь введет: 2, программа должна тоже самое сделать, но уже через побочную диагональ

```
n = int(input())
diagonal = int(input())
A = [[1,2,3],[0,9,4],[7,6,5]] 
#for i in range(n): 
#    row = input().split() 
#    for i in range(len(row)): 
#        row[i] = int(row[i]) 
#    A.append(row) 
print(A) 
if diagonal == 1:
    for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if i < j:
                    A[i][j],A[j][i] = A[j][i],A[i][j]
    print(A)
if diagonal == 2:
    for i in range(n):
        if i < n - 1:
            for j in range(n):
                if j < n - i:
                    print(A[i][j])
                    A[i][j],A[j][i] = A[j][i],A[i][j]
    print(A)
```

Я закомментировал строки ввода матрицы, для удобства. Матрица квадратная, пользователь сам выбирает NxN. Функция Print в условие побочной диагонали дана для вывода тех элементов, что находятся выше побочной диагонали. 
Прошу сильно не критиковать, изучаю основы, и решаю каждый день задачи по питону, нарешал чисел, строк, обыкновенных массивов, но вот с двумерными, застрял почему-то. Спасибо за понимание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код полностью такой же как и в первом случае, только меняешь другие элементы и по условию отзеркаленному в одну сторону

```
for i in range(n): 
    for j in range(n): 
        if n-1-i < j: 
            A[i][j],A[n-1-j][n-1-i] = A[n-1-j][n-1-i],A[i][j]
```

< или > - значения не имеет.

n-1-i - в условии задает проход в обратном порядке: 2,1,0 . Иногда это переносят в цикл как range(n-1,-1,-1)

А дальше смотри какие элементы менять местами..

Answer (score 0):

```py
n = int(input())
diagonal = int(input())
A = [[1,2,3],[0,9,4],[7,6,5]] 
#for i in range(n): 
#    row = input().split() 
#    for i in range(len(row)): 
#        row[i] = int(row[i]) 
#    A.append(row) 
print(A) 
if diagonal == 1:
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i < j:
                A[i][j],A[j][i] = A[j][i],A[i][j]
    print(A)
if diagonal == 2:
    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(n - 1):
            if i + j < n:
                A[i][j],A[n-j-1][n-i-1] = A[n-j-1][n-i-1],A[i][j]
    print(A)
```